# Unique Key [Customised]

Tags: oracle

I have a table to store address. There is a field to identify the present or active address. An employee can have multiple address but only one active address. There are only two states of address_status field, i.e. present and old. They are denoted by ids 1 for active and 2 for old. So in the table one employee can contain only one active address or address_status = 1 but multiple address_status = 2.

Kindly suggest how to tackle the mentioned scenario.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you describe the issues you are having?

Comment: Use `address_status = 1` for active address and `address_status = NULL` for old addresses. Then you can define a unique Key on `(address, address_status)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    address VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    address_status INTEGER,
    address_status_text VARCHAR2(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE address_status WHEN 1 THEN 'active' ELSE 'old' END)
    );

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_STATUS CHECK (ADDRESS_STATUS IS NULL OR ADDRESS_STATUS = 1);
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_ACTIVE UNIQUE (ADDRESS_STATUS);


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (address, address_status) VALUES ('New York', 1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (address, address_status) VALUES ('Houston', NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (address, address_status) VALUES ('Houston', NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (address, address_status) VALUES ('Los Angeles', NULL);

SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE;


+----------------------------------------------+
|ADDRESS    |ADDRESS_STATUS|ADDRESS_STATUS_TEXT|
+----------------------------------------------+
|Houston    |              |old                |
|Houston    |              |old                |
|Los Angeles|              |old                |
|New York   |1             |active             |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional unique index like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ADDRESS_IDX01
ON ADDRESS (CASE WHEN ADDRESS_STATUS = 1
THEN EMPLOYEE_ID -- please change the name of the colum refering to employee or accordingly
ELSE NULL
END);
```

Cheers!!